Windows logs not getting shipped in graylog hosted in AKS
We are setting up graylog in AKS. For that kongz/graylog helm is used for setting up graylog, mongodb and opensearch in azure Kubernetes.
Along with nginx-ingress controller has been set to access graylog outside AKS and external IP is mapped with DNS. I am able to access graylog using DNS from my local machine.
Now, we need to ship windows logs from machine hosted in azure into graylog. For that, we have installed graylog sidecar and winlogbeat in windows machine and added beats stream in graylog. However, still we are not able to get logs from machine in graylog. Any idea what are we missing here ?
I am expecting windows logs to be shipped in graylog hosted in AKS
